# IIS (w3wp.exe) runs with a User Name of the App Pool that doesn't belong to Users, Groups, or Built-in security principals

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-server-2008, orchardcms

The Orchardcms Application works fine accept when trying to Install new modules using the module installer within the dashboard. I get this error below.

*Install package failed
Package installation failed: There was an error installing the requested package. This can happen if the server does not have write access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site. If the site is running in shared hosted environement, adding write access to these folders sometimes needs to be done manually through the Hoster control panel. Once Themes and Modules have been installed, it is recommended to remove write access to these folders.*

It seems that the installed IIS 7 App Pool (Presumably installed with Orchard in Web Platform Installer) using ApplicationPoolIdentity. w3wp.exe runs with username orchardmain (this is what i named my application I could have left it to default orchard) Though the problem with this that I can't update my NTFS permissions for orchardmain as when trying to add a username in permissions it can't find any  Users, Groups, or Built-in security principals with the name OrchardMain.

Is it best practise to change the App Pool to run under an User / Service Account that doesn't behave like this, or is there just a little thing i can do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IIS APPPOOL\OrchardMain` as the object name when editing permissions.

See this [blog post](http://alasdaircs.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/granting-directory-permissions-to-a-website-using-iis-apppool/) for details.